# jQuery .val() program

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in jQuery and javascript. So please, bear with me. In this program, I have 3 textboxes whose ids are: `a1`, `aa1` and `baa1`.

`a1` is the net weight; `aa1` is the rate; and `baa1` is a readonly textbox with the product of `#a1` and `#aa1`.

Please have a look at my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5N74b/1/). I have written a program to calculate the product. But due to some reason, it is not working.

```
function amtcal(id)
{    
var ntwt=$("#a1").val();
var rval=$("#aa1").val();
var product=rval*ntwt;
$("#baa1").val(product);
}
```

Please tell me what's wrong in this.

Comment: Put the code into the question and please define "not working".

Comment: How about starting with descriptive id's so that this isn't so darn confusing ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues here, but lets start with the one which has nothing to do with your code. In JSFiddle you get to choose where the javascript is placed - the default is `onload` so the javascript produced in the output of your original jsfiddle looks like:

```
$(window).load(function(){
function amtcal(id)
{    
var ntwt=$("#a1").val();
var rval=$("#aa1").val();
var product=rval*ntwt;
$("#baa1").val(product);
}
});
```

That means your function is scoped inside that window load function, and so is completely inaccessible from the DOM. hence the error:

> ReferenceError: amtcal is not defined

This can be fixed by selecting "No wrap - in head" on the left hand side.

So what's wrong with your actual code? An easy to spot issue is that you are reading the content of your two editable text boxes using jQuery:

```
var ntwt=$("#a1").val();
var rval=$("#aa1").val();
```

Thats ok, but textboxes return strings, and string cannot be multiplied, so you must convert them to a number. I'll assume you wanted integers:

```
var ntwt= parseInt($("#a1").val(),10);
var rval= parseInt($("#aa1").val(),10);
```

At this point it works, so long as you edit the second textbox first. You need to call the same function from both textboxes:

```
<input placeholder="Net Wt" id="a1" onchange="amtcal(this.id)">
<input id="aa1"  placeholder="Rate" style="width:50px;" onchange="amtcal(this.id)">
```

At this point all works: http://jsfiddle.net/8JA4s/

However, you're  mixing jQuery and vanilla javascript/DOM. Its often easier to stick with one or the other to save confusion.

The typical way to do this is to attach event handlers using jQuery [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('#a1, #aa1').on('change',function(){
   var ntwt=parseInt($("#a1").val(),10);
   var rval=parseInt($("#aa1").val(),10);
   var product=rval*ntwt;
   $("#baa1").val(product);
});
```

You, of course, remove the event handlers in the DOM when doing it this way. This **should** be placed `onLoad` in jsfiddle for it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/8JA4s/2/

Comment: Great Answer @Jamiec. Thanks for the help. I was waiting for this kind of an answer.

Comment: No probs. Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using inline js, bind it:

As per Shea's suggestion, use onkeyup instead of change.

```
$("#a1, #aa1").on('keyup', function(){
   amtcal($(this).prop('id'));
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5N74b/8/)

Comment: also, that's only going to trigger after you've lost focus to the textbox. I would recommend using the `onkeyup` event instead of `onchange`.

Comment: not working...answer coming to 0 and when the textbox is again edited, then the correct answer is shown

Comment: @BenLind Make sure you are using jquery 1.9 like in the fiddle

Comment: @PatsyIssa , I am using the fiddle whose link is given above.

Comment: @BenLind check the updated fiddle, it was returning 0 since the function only goes off when you update the #a1 value, with the `$("#a1, #aa1")` selector it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you look in console, you'll see that it says `amtcal` is not defined, because it is processed after the HTML - use javascript to attach the event handler instead of the `onchange=""` attribute.

HTML:

```
<input placeholder="Net Wt" id="a1">
<input id="aa1"  placeholder="Rate" style="width:50px;">
<input id="baa1" readonly>
```

JS:

```
function amtcal()
{    
    var ntwt=$("#a1").val();
    var rval=$("#aa1").val();
    var product=rval*ntwt;
    $("#baa1").val(product);
}

$("#a1,#aa1").change(amtcal);//easier to use if both inputs trigger the update
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SmokeyPHP/5N74b/5/)

Comment: By the way, as he uses jQuery it can be written as $('#a1').on('change', function() {...}); or kind of

Comment: @Victor Yea noticed that as i posted my answer - I've updated it to use jQuery syntax